# Error in React Native code

Tags: android, react-native

I want to learn React Native so i tried to follow the doc page of React Native
[React Native DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

I want to create an app in Native code so I followed the instruction. when I ran the app I got following errors:
[image]

Looking at the Build Successful I was happy but when I checked my android emulator it was showing unexpected error.

[image]

I have added the screenshot of the error in my android Logcat

[image]

I tried to reset cache but it failed.

[image]

I am totally new at this so i didn't get why am i getting this error. I searched by my self and there is another way to create a new app using expo. Creating an app using expo and then ejecting will make the app to use Native code but after creating in expo it works perfectly fine but after ejecting it doesn't works.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "aowinas",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "jest": "^23.2.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try in real device?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Can you share you package.json file too?

Comment: I have added the package.json file up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using the following step:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-android
npm uninstall react-native
npm install --save react-native@0.55.4
react-native run-android
npm install --save babel-core@latest babel-loader@latest
npm uninstall --save babel-preset-react-native
npm install --save babel-preset-react-native@4.0.0
react-native run-android
```